# Identify the font color for item in JavaList [QTP, UFT, VBScript]

Tags: vbscript, qtp

**How to identify the font color for an item in a JavaList?**

I have a challenge I can't solve and need some guidance.  I have a JavaList with several items (ie. rows, where each row is a string of text).  This JavaList is like a log file where the font color will be color coded ('red' for something bad, 'green' for something good).  I'm trying to read through the list and identify (1) the text and [solved] (2) the font color for each line [how?].

Here's where I need some help.  I still yet to figure out how to determine the font color for each line

### Sample Code

```
desiredItemNumber = 20    'this value is arbitrary or determined elsewhere

Set myJavaList = JavaWindow(ABC).JavaList(XYZ)  
myLineItem = myJavaList(desiredItemNumber)
myFontColor = ????

print myLineItem          'this prints the text as desired
print myFontColor
```

I unsuccessfully tried **.ChildObjects** but I believe UFT sees the line items as 'items' and not 'objects'

```
<did not work>
L1_objects = myJavaList.ChildObjects
myFontColor = L1_objects(desiredItemNumber).GetROProperty('foreground')
```

any help is appreciated